Why I'm getting "ReferenceError: e is not defined" error in my cloud shell terminal when I'm trying to run "node importTestData customers_1000.csv"?
Recently, I was attempting to complete a Qwiklab, Importing Data to a Firestore Database, on the Google Cloud Skills Boost website. Everything was fine until I reached the 4th task, "Task 4. Import the test customer data." When I tried to run the command "node importTestData customers_1000.csv" in the Cloud Shell terminal, I encountered this "ReferenceError: e is not defined" error, as shown in this image. 
Request: Please let me know if anyone has encountered this error while completing this lab manual, which was last updated and tested on February 28, 2024. I have seen videos related to the completion of this lab on YouTube, but those are 9-10 months old.
But I was expecting this result as shown in this image. 

I think there's a bug in the importTestData function. Please edit importTestData.js. Does line #12 read const parser = csv.parse({ columns: true, delimiter: ',' }, async function (err, records) {? If so, then if line #13 reads if (e) {, please edit it to read if (err) {. Then try it again.

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others
As mentioned by @DazWilkin

I think there's a bug in the importTestData function. Please edit importTestData.js. Does line #12 read const parser = csv.parse({ columns: true, delimiter: ',' }, async function (err, records) {? If so, then if line #13 reads if (e) {, please edit it to read if (err) {. Then try it again.

